# Relation between class A and class B

Tags: java

```
public class A {
    private String str;
    public void setString(String pStr){
        str = pStr;
    }

    private class B {
        public String getStr(){
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

a)What is the relation between class A and class B ?
b)And why Class B can access private field of A (str) ?

Is it derived or other else?

Comment: you need to do your homework. it's **your** homework and not ours, for a reason. and no, these two classes are not related in any immediately meaningful way (you could come up with artificial stuff like "the same programmer wrote them", but that's irrelevant, presumably.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an nested class i.e. class within class. It's similar to you defining field and passing value like say `private String mystr = new String(str);` So here you can access private field str and pass it onto String.

Similarly you have defined non static class within the outer class which would access private/protected/public field defined in outer class.

You call a class as derived, if say it extends another class. Something like:

```
public class MyParentClass {}
public class MySubClass extends MyParentClass {}
```

Answer (score 0):

class B is private so it only can be created from within the class. That means that class A is always present in some form. When you make class B static you wont have any access to class A's variables because it is static.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:
a) There is no relationship between one and the other as you have shown in
b) Class B can't access it because it is private on A and there is no relationship (read inheritance) in the code shown between the two. Even if there was, privates are not inherited

Take a look at these links to better understand inheritance and private properties:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html
- [Private methods in Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392051/private-methods-in-inheritance)
- [private method in inheritance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461867/private-method-in-inheritance-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Class B is kind of member of class A. When a class has a private member, other members of the same class can have access to it. Same way class B can access private members of class A in your case. This is not a relationship of any kind. It is just class within the class.